# Convert pptx files to pdf files in itext and Apache

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

I am trying to convert a pptx file to a pdf file in iText and Apache, but I got this problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/poi/hslf/model/TextPainter$Key
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNZhn.png) for this problem.

[image]

I have already added the poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar file, but it is still not working.
Does anybody have any idea on this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: No idea at all without your pivotal code and your pptx file, no.

Comment: As far as I know,  iText =/= POI

Comment: You neither show code nor the stack trace of the exception. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: I added the stack trace. Please click "Error".

Comment: As far as I can see only poi classes are involved in your stack trace. You appear not to have all required poi jars 
In your class path or at least not the correct versions of them.

Comment: And if you fiddle around with your Jars... please use a current version and not something 3.9-ish ... I've changed the rendering code to SL-common packages already a while ago ...